# crear 2 parametros (PostMapping) con diferentes entidades

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Buenas tengo esta consulta quiero pasar el parametro contribuyente en el mismo PATH. como este ejemplo en el
**@PostMapping("/documentos/{documentoId}/contribuyente/{contribuyenteId}/entidades")**
como tendria que modificar el codigo createEntidad para juntarlo y crear la entidad con documento y contribuyente ya que son de diferentes entities solo quiero atraparlos por id ?
..................................................
..................................................

```
    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    @PostMapping("/documentos/{documentoId}/contribuyente/{contribuyenteId}/entidades")
    public Object createEntidad(@PathVariable int documentoId,@PathVariable int contribuyenteId , @Valid @RequestBody Entidad entidad, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return this.validar(result);
        }
        return documentoRepo.findById(documentoId).map(r -> {
            entidad.setDocumento(r);
            return entidadRepo.save(entidad);
        }).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundExpcetion("Documento no encontrado!"));
    }
```

Aqui estan mis entities ENTIDAD Y DOCUMENTO Y CONTRIBUYENTE :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_entidad")
public class Entidad implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(length = 11)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "nro_documento", length = 25)
    private int nroDocumento;

    @Column(name = "razon_social", length = 100)
    @NotEmpty
    private String razonSocial;

    @Column(name = "nombre_comercial", length = 100)
    @NotEmpty
    private String nombreComercial;

    @Column(length = 250)
    @NotEmpty
    private String direccion;

    @Column(length = 50)
    @NotEmpty
    private String telefono;

    private Boolean estado;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tipodocumento_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value ={"entidad","handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer"}) 
    private Documento documento;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tipocontribuyente_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value ={"entidad","handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer"}) 
    private Contribuyente contribuyente;




}
```

=======================================================================

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_tipo_documento")
public class Documento implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(length = 11)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 20)
    @NotEmpty
    private String codigo;

    @Column(length = 100)
    @NotEmpty
    private String nombre;

    @Column(length = 200)
    private String descripcion;

    private Boolean estado;
    

    @OneToOne(mappedBy ="documento",fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value ={"documento","handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer"}) 
    private Entidad entidad;

}
```

=======================================================================

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_tipo_contribuyente")
public class Contribuyente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(length = 11)
    private int id;
    @Column(length = 50)
    @NotEmpty
    private String nombre;

    private Boolean estado;

    

    @OneToOne(mappedBy ="contribuyente",fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value ={"contribuyente","handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer"}) 
    private Entidad entidad;




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que, dentro del .map, tendrías que recuperar el contribuyente y setearlo a la entidad que estás construyendo, algo así;

```
@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
@PostMapping("/documentos/{documentoId}/contribuyente/{contribuyenteId}/entidades")
public Object createEntidad(@PathVariable int documentoId,@PathVariable int contribuyenteId , @Valid @RequestBody Entidad entidad, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return this.validar(result);
    }
    return documentoRepo.findById(documentoId).map(r -> {
        entidad.setDocumento(r);
        Entidad contribuyente = contribuyenteRepo.findById(contribuyenteId).orElse(null);
        antidad.setContribuyente(contribuyente);
        return entidadRepo.save(entidad);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Documento no encontrado!"));
}
```

Lo he escrito sin verificar así que seguramente no te funcione el copy-paste, pero para que tengas una idea, lo que te recomendaría es reestructurar el método, ya que me parece un poco confuso crear tanto código dentro de una función lambda, pero esto es una apreciación personal.

Un saludo.